# Trouble With a <div> Not Rotating Where I Want It To

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm relatively new to html and css so I apologise in advance if my code is sloppy and/or redundant.

http://jsfiddle.net/t16uf9sv/1/

As can be seen in the linked fiddle, I'm in the middle of making an interactive menu button that will eventually expand to reveal prompts to navigate the site. For now though, I've just been trying to get the vertical bar of the plus to rotate 90 degrees to form a minus when clicked. [ + ] ---> [ - ].

When trying to perform this with the attached code, the element just doesn't go where I want it to.

I have a feeling that the problem may lie in how I went about centering the bar elements (.vertical, .horizontal) within the square (.menu).

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <a href="#"><div class="menu">
        <div class="plus">
            <div class="vertical"></div>
            <div class="horizontal"></div>
        </div>
        </div></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    position: relative;
}

body {
    background: #212121;
}

.nav {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 326px;
    margin-right: 965px;
    margin-left: 250px;
}

.menu {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 2.5px solid #ffffff;
    -o-transition:.2s;
    -ms-transition:.2s;
    -moz-transition:.2s;
    -webkit-transition:.2s;
    transition:.2s;
}

.plus {
    position: relative;
    padding: 25px;
}

.vertical {
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 25px;
    width: 2.5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transition:.2s;
    -ms-transition:.2s;
    -moz-transition:.2s;
    -webkit-transition:.2s;
    transition:.2s;
}

.horizontal {
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 2.5px;
    width: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transition:.2s;
    -ms-transition:.2s;
    -moz-transition:.2s;
    -webkit-transition:.2s;
    transition:.2s;
}

.menu:hover {
    background: #ffffff;
}

.menu:hover .vertical, .menu:hover .horizontal {
    background: #212121;
}

.menu:active .vertical {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

I'm starting to lose my mind trying to figure this out, so if anyone could help in any way I would greatly appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're telling it to simply rotate 90degrees, which is what it's doing. When it rotates, it loses it's position of `top:50%` and `left:50%`, you need to redefine those in your `:active` snippet:

```
.menu:active .vertical {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

just add:

```
 top: 25%;
  left: 46%;
```

And it will do exactly what you need :)

---

**[Working Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/t16uf9sv/2/)**

```
 .menu:active .vertical {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        top: 25%;
        left: 46%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is just add `opacity: 0`, and change the `top` and `left` attributes in the [css](/questions/tagged/css) under `menu:active .vertical`:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    position: relative;
}

body {
    background: #212121;
}

.nav {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 965px;
    margin-left: 250px;
}

.menu {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 2.5px solid #ffffff;
    -o-transition:.2s;
    -ms-transition:.2s;
    -moz-transition:.2s;
    -webkit-transition:.2s;
    transition:.2s;
}

.plus {
    position: relative;
    padding: 25px;
}

.vertical {
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 25px;
    width: 2.5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transition:.2s;
    -ms-transition:.2s;
    -moz-transition:.2s;
    -webkit-transition:.2s;
    transition:.2s;
}

.horizontal {
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 2.5px;
    width: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transition:.2s;
    -ms-transition:.2s;
    -moz-transition:.2s;
    -webkit-transition:.2s;
    transition:.2s;
}

.menu:hover {
    background: #ffffff;
}

.menu:hover .vertical, .menu:hover .horizontal {
    background: #212121;
}

.menu:active .vertical {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    top: 25%;
    left: 40%;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <a href="#"><div class="menu">
        <div class="plus">
            <div class="vertical"></div>
            <div class="horizontal"></div>
        </div>
        </div></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the rotate is relative to the position before the

`transform:translate(-50%, -50%);`

that you used to center it (if you remove this you will notice it rotates correctly but in the wrong place).

I would say the best thing to do here is not use `translate` in positioning, as the size is fixed. I only use it for variable size elements.

Instead just remove the transform, set the dimensions to fixed sizes, as so:

```
.vertical {
    background: #ffffff;
    height:50%;
    top:25%;
    position: absolute;
    width:5%;
    left:47.5%;
    -o-transition:.2s;
    -ms-transition:.2s;
    -moz-transition:.2s;
    -webkit-transition:.2s;
    transition:.2s;
}
```

I estimated this so it was about the same as yours. Also this way it is relative to the screen size (although it is small enough to not matter really).